# How to compare different SQL tables and look for differences?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datatable, compare

I need to compare different ID's to each other in the same data table, all the ID's have the same information I just need to spot the differences and show them to the user when there are changes found in the database.

What would be the easyest way of doing this? I have no clue at all.

All the items that needs to be compared have a Primary key for themself and a Forgeign key that groups them up together ( They are search results from scraping google ) by the query the user searched for.

When the user searches for the second time about something the program needs to show the difference in search results.

Does anyone have a idea about how to code this?

Kind regards,
Martijn

Comment: Hi Martijn, maybe I don't get it right, but there seems to be a contradiction between the title of your question and what your are writing in detail. Are there really different tables (as it says in the title) or just one (see first sentence). Or do you refer to the result when saying 'in the same data table'? Also a short example of table(s) and desired result would help a lot.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, it's a hard question for me to describe, the item's that I want to compare are in the exact same Table. ( For Example Result 1, that has A title and a URL, and Result 2 that also has A title and a URL ) and I want to compare these 2 results, if the results are the same nothing should happen except the first one should be removed. if the 2 results are different than I want something to show up like a messagebox.  I've thought about putting the 2 results in Lists and than use Lists.Except function comparing the 2 Lists and I'm currently trying that out atm.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have your FK's set up.  If you have an FK constraint or if you just use an FK - if the latter, can't you just check which id's have null or empty FK's?

Are you asking how to get the tables set up too?